# Laravel with-count subquery without relation

Tags: laravel, count, eloquent, relation

My target is to get collection of books with count of matches book.names in another table without relation

I get collection like this

```
$books = Books::paginate(20);
```

What I need now is to get the count of matches like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `posts` WHERE `body` LIKE '%book.name%'
```

How can I do this with one query and avoiding unnecessary queries for each model, like eager loading

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with eager loading without loading all post. There is a method called `withCount`

**Books.php**

```
public function posts() {
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class, 'post_id', 'id');
}
```

One way to find all post related to book is

```
$books = Books::withCount(['posts' => function ($query) use($searchTerm) {
    $query->where('body', 'like', $searchTerm);
}])->get();

//How to retrieve
$book = $books->first()->posts_count.
```

You can find more information about withCount on laravel documentation [website.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations)

**Approach 2: Without Eager Loading**

```
$books = Books::select('*')->addSelect(DB::raw("SELECT COUNT(*) as post_count FROM `posts` WHERE `body` LIKE '%book.name%' ")->get(); //This will return collection with post_count.
```

***Note: Not tested***